# Jenkins pipeline advise required

Tags: linux, jenkins, sftp

I want to create a very simple pipeline that will clone a repo from Github and then copy a JSON file to a directory. **But there is a catch here and requires your guide** if that is possible or not. It is on a Linux machine and the folder structure is like this:-

```
/var/www/myjenkins.com/
/var/www/myapi.com/html/json/
```

On my Linux machine, this Jenkin is running which is deployed on the location as `/var/www/myjenkins.com/` and the new pipeline which I need to create in Jenkin has to perform the job of copying a JSON file (after git clone) to another location as /var/www/myapi.com/html/json/ which is out of root level of Jenkins. Is that really possible to traverse out of the root level of Jenkins then copy the file into another location?

Would be glad if you can advise on this. Thanks

Comment: If the build is executed by a user that has the permission to write files in the specified location, it is possible. This depends on your applied user management. When you have root as default build user it will be fine, but this leads to security issues. All other users must be given permissions explicitly.

Comment: as @SvenKrüger said, it should be possible. Just try it. Put a `mv /var/www/myapi.com/html/json/my.json .` and see what happens. The most probable error is permission denied, but it might as well just work.

Comment: Thanks guys I can list on the directory but cannot copy the file due to permission issue. Im trying to execute the shell command on Jenkins server. I can see that 'jenkin' user has been used to perform this operation. Is it possible to make this pipeline/shell commands run using my own credentials because my id has got permission and I was able to manually perform SFTP put command earlier

Comment: You will need to run the command with sudo -u